# Heroku scheduling for one-off jobs

Tags: ruby, heroku

I want to schedule jobs to happen at a specific time and date but I'm getting confused by the wide range of options for doing so.

My requirements:

- These are not recurring jobs, they only need to happen once at a specified date and time
- I'm the only user of the app so don't need to deal with heavy traffic
- I would like to minimise the cost of running this on Heroku, i.e. not paying idle dynos

Any tips on which combinations of gems etc. to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into using https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler? You'll need the Redis To Go addon on Heroku. This will cost you $36 a month because you'll need a scheduler process running alongside your web process. However, I've done this for free. See the README here: https://github.com/austinthecoder/pinger.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Due to Heroku Scheduler (default Heroku add-on) doesn't allow you to schedule your job as specific time. It is best to rely on a clock process to do the job. Gem such has Clockwork could be set up please see Heroku's [Clockwork guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-ruby). You need to combine Clock with a background queuer such as `resque` or `sidekiq`. I highly recommend you go for `sidekiq`. Please bear in mind that both resque and sidekiq requires `redis` which is offered by `redistogo` add-on and it will cost you money to run it.